# Error 400 when using Jira REST API from Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, rest, jira, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create an issue in Jira through REST API from Oracle APEX, but I'm always getting only Error 400 in response. By the way, everything is fine when I read issues with GET method, by both POST and PUT cause error.

I used quite a simple piece of code:

```
DECLARE
req utl_http.req;
res utl_http.resp;
url varchar2(4000) := 'http://host:port/rest/api/latest/issue/';
buffer varchar2(4000);
content varchar2(4000) :=
'{
"fields": {
"project":
{ 
"id": "10000"
},
"summary": "Auto generated",
"description": "Creating of an issue using the REST API",
"issuetype": {
"id": "3"
}
}
}';


begin

-- Make request
req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization', 'Basic bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
utl_http.write_text(req, content);

-- Get response
res := utl_http.get_response(req);
utl_http.read_text(res, buffer);
```

Response from server contains only res.status_code = 400 and res.reason_phrase = null. I've studied quite a lot of materials, but none of them could resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

400 means Bad Request and JIRA generally outputs really informational error messages as to why it failed. Capture the actual body of the response instead of just the status code and/or reason and see what it says.

Comment: Actually, UTL_HTTP.READ_TEST(res, buffer) now returns following: {"errorMessages":["No content to map to Object due to end of input"]}

Comment: That message usually means the JSON in the body is either missing or invalid. I checked the one you tried to submit and it seems to be valid which could mean that it's not being properly attached to the request. Or, alternatively, are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes, I used a few examples of JSON with the same result. And I'm sure in URL due to successfull GET requests. Probably, UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(req, content) produces some kind of improper format of request body? I didn't get clear vision of this procedures yet.

Comment: That would be great if someone could just try this code on another apex/jira servers. There is possibility of successful run...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out, what was the problem. Despite of using HTP/1.1 protocol version (by default), it is still mandatory to specify Content-Length header (measured in bytes).